# Mysql service wont start on windows 2008 server r1

Tags: mysql, windows, windows-server-2008

About a month ago, after I changed a startup parameter on mysql administrator, my server got  frozen. So I rebooted. Ever since my mysql service wont start on startup or when I try to start it manually. I can only start mysql in console mode (mysqld --console).
I have tried many things but none of them worked:

- I have uninstalled and rebooted the server and then installed again;
- I have deleted everything in program files folder related to mysql and installed again
- I have deleted all the related files in programdata folder
- I have treid to use 3307 port instead of 3306 but still not worked

Now when I install mysql again it can never manage to start the service during the setup procccess, so it never manages to end of installation. But I can still start the mysql server on command line with "mysqld --console"
I tried to look into the event lgo , the only error I see is plugin federated is disabled, I looked for solutitions about this error but none worked for me. I believe this might be something abput windows. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Check the user credentials for the service and any possible dependencies.  Did you undo the start up parameter?

Comment: yes I did undo the startup parameter, but still not working.

Comment: Then I would uninstall, delete, clean out the registry, and reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall, delete and all the cleanup you did above.

Additionaly manually delete MySQL Windows service.
This can be done by command line using `sc stop MySQL` then `sc delete MySQL`.

Before installing, a reboot shouldn't be necessary.

Recreating the Windows service manually, if the installer doesn't do it for you, can be done using `"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld" --install` (as the manual says).

If the MySQL installer has installed the service with on demand start-up type, you can edit to start automatically at boot using: `sc config MySQL start= auto` (the white space after the = sign is intentional and needed). Afterwards you can start the service using `sc start MySQL`.